# how to link between my GUI my operational class?

Tags: java, swing

i have a class `UDPServer` that contains the main method and i built a GUI by window builder in a new class that extends `JFrame` and all my classes in the same package

and I want to know how to map this code to my GUI and my `actionPerformed` methods ?

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException, SocketException 
{   
    final int port = 55555;     // Add server port number.
    DatagramSocket sock  = new DatagramSocket (port); 
    while (true) 
    {
        UDPServer server = new UDPServer (sock);
        server.getRequest ();
        server.useRequest ();
        server.makeResponse();
        server.sendResponse ();
    }
} // End of main
```

because i have a text field to let the server listen to a what will be entered and a button to make the server listen and similar things like this to do a chat application that is similar to remote desktop.

Answer (score 2):

To link non-GUI "model" code with your GUI "view" code,

- You first will want to create OOP-compliant objects complete with non-static variables, constructors, methods including getters, setters, etc. The code you've posted is nothing but the most basic static main method, and is thus no where near able to be simply integrated with your GUI.
- Your control code, which includes your event listeners, would then call the model code to have it perform its non-GUI actions, in your case the ActionListeners (control) would then ask the model (the I/O classes) to send information over your socket(s).
- The model, here your communications code, would then either notify the control or the view (depending on your program set up), of any change in state -- here that would include notification of data packages received.
- Then the view (your GUI) can extract this information and display it.
- You must take care to be sure that long-running code be called on background threads such as that provided by a SwingWorker.
- You must take care that all calls that change the state of Swing components be made on the Swing event thread.
- You will want to Google and then study articles on the MVC design, and then incorporate its principles or one of its variants, in your program.